# Can anybody explain these WebGL snippets?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I am learning webgl and fully confused now.
I am going through [this website](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html) and the comments written with code half explains for a beginner like me.

For example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
if(!gl) {
    return;
}

//Setup GLSL
var program = createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);
gl.useProgram(program);

//Look up where the vertex data needs to go
var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');     

//create a buffer and put a single CLIPSPACE rectangle in it.
var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1.0, -1.0,
                                                 1.0, -1.0,
                                                 -1.0, 1.0,
                                                 -1.0, 1.0,
                                                 1.0, -1.0,
                                                 1.0, 1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
//draw
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

In the above snippet, the line

```
var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
```

indicates it got the position where the vertex needs to go , but I didn't find anything specific in vertex shaders

```
attribute vec2 a_position;
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
}
```

How can we say where is the position?

Also the Float32Array , why are we using that at all ,is there any scenario where we can use it in real time, I am totally confused with these shaders.

I also read GLSL essentials ,to get some shaders knowledge, but still confused with these things. Can somebody put some light on to it?

Comment: Does this help? http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html

Comment: yes, I have posted many questions on SO, and you have answered all of them with great commitment, would you like to teach me online  ,if yes ,what's your quote(you can mail me@subhasishdash60@gmail.com if you want)?

Comment: Okay , one thing I understood now .i.e we should use gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, SIZE_OF_FLOAT32ARRAY/2); . But now my doubt is what does the values represent in the Float32Array ,If I change the values ,I cannot see any change ?

Comment: this command `gl.bufferData(...)` **copies** the data in the `Float32Array` to the GPU. If you edit the values in the `Float32Array` you need to call `gl.bufferData(...)` again to copy the new values to the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

The Float32Array contains all the vertices that will go through the shading pipeline. 
In your vertex shader you assign `gl_Position`to be a 4-dimensional vector with x and y belonging to your inserted vertices. So a_Position contains the values you passed in your array and the vertex shader will be run for every single vertex out there.

So this shader hardly does anything. In a real application, you can do several transformations and lighting operations etc. here.

If you run this program you should see 2 triangles being drawn (1 rectangle). That's because the array contains 6 2d-values that assign to 2 triangles. 
Check out more information on the openGL pipeline [here.](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview)

Comment: You seem to have good knowledge on webgl , would you mind teaching me for a price money?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've got a full time job and a degree to pursue :/

Comment: Okay , one thing I understood now .i.e we should use `gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, SIZE_OF_FLOAT32ARRAY/2);` . But now my doubt is what does the values represent in the Float32Array ,If I change the values ,I cannot see any change ?

Comment: They represent the position in the scene. If you change them drastically enough, you should see a change.

Comment: Also, if I assume every 2 vertices as x and y , I am still failing to understand why the full canvas is occupied when I am only drawing one triangle . `var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([100, -100,
                    150,  125,
                    -175,  100]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
    //draw
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);`

Comment: the whole canvas might be occupied, because the triangle is that large, have you tried using values like 0.1?

Comment: Using this , but still full canvas is occupied : `gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0.1, -0.1,
                    0.1,  0.1,
                    -0.1,  0.1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);`

Comment: It might still be too big, continue following the article :)